# Setup of a Python project with sole purpose of running performance tests

Tags: deployment, pytest, setuptools

I'm working on a project that will run in a CICD pipeline (GitLab) and will run performance tests on various database drivers and stores the results.

The project will be deployed using Docker. Ideally, I would like to build a Docker image with a wheel package of my project and then just run the package to perform the tests.

I've used similar deployment setup in a different project that had a regular entrypoint with a main function. In that case, it was easy to set up the build using setuptools and `pyproject.toml` file.

I'm not sure how to approach this since in this case, the entrypoint is parametrized pytest test.

Will I be even able to run tests from the installed wheel package? Should I invoke pytest programmatically from an explicit entrypoint instead use pytest to invoke unit tests that test the modules in the project, but do not run the actual performance tests?